Can I access row names directly through sequelize (v6)
is there a way to somehow (through for in loop for example) access the column names which were defined in sequelize.define?
Lets say this is one of my tables:
const Categories = sequelize.define(
    'category',
    {
        category: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        created_at: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE(6)
        },
        updated_at: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE(6)
        },
        created_by_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        updated_by_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
    },
    {
        freezeTableName: true,
        timestamps: false,
        createdAt: false,
        updatedAt: false,
    }
)

I know I can access the names of tables through sequelize.models. Can I access the category through sequelize? Trying to access the category (and other rows) mentioned below.
        category: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },

Thank you.
Edit:
I would like to access the column names without actually using their names. So I would like to avoid this kind of syntax Categories.category as I would need to defined the logic for each table/Model. Instead I would like to access the column names somewhat like this for (const key in Categories.columnNames) { if (key !== 'created_at'){...} }

Maybe I'm missing something, but: you already know the column names, they're right there in your model's source? The one thing to remember is that on the SQL side, Sequelize will (obviously) use the real column names, but on the JS side it renames them to proper JS naming conventions, so a column like some_column_name becomes a JS property someColumnName.

That's true. The thing is, I have a lot of tables with not many columns so (mostly) the table structures aren't too complicated. It would save me a lot of time if I could simply loop through all the columns in a specific table and use only the columns I need.
TLDR; Instead of writing specific logic for each table i could generalize it.

You'll save yourself a lot of dev headaches by just making those models, honestly. It might be more work up front, but indirection in Sequelize is bad enough already, you don't want to add yet another layer of "where the hell is this set/coming from/etc". You can, of course, make that easier on yourself by getting your db to output/dump your entire db's schema, and then regexing that into something you can quickly rewrite to valid JS.

Thanks. I'll take that into consideration. Just to be sure though, your are talking about building a specific function for each of the tables?

Model, not function (so one sequelize.define for every table). With that: yes. Though naming wise you generally want your db table to be a plural (since a table houses many, many records) and the Sequelize model to be a singular. E.g a categories table on the db side, but a Category model in JS, so that things like Category.findOrCreate(...) makes sense to people reading the code.

Ah, then there was a misunderstanding. I already have the Models defined. The thing is, I need to populate the database (from csv/xlsx for example) and so, need to reference specific columns. I imagine writing a separate logic for different Models (referencing a specific column) is less reasonable then writing a general function and discarding the unnecessary columns.

Found it.
You can get all the column names through Categories.tableAttributes.
